# Debian User can't overwrite, yet belongs to Group

Tags: debian, group-policy

- In Debian I have a user called `jesse`
- I have a group called `www-data` for Apache2
- I have a folder called `/htdocs`
- `htdocs` belongs to `user:group` of `www-data:www-data`

I do not understand why the user `jesse` cannot overwrite files in the directory when he belongs within the `www-data` group.

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing?

```
$ groups jesse
jesse : jesse sudo www-data
```

Comment: what is mode for directory `/htdocs`? i.e. what does `ls -l htdocs` show?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      395 Sep 21 02:56 index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user `jesse` is member of group `www-data`, then to be able to create new files (and edit/delete existing ones) in directory `/htdata` that directory must have group write permission enabled (your current setup does not!). In other words, `ls -ld /htdata` should show:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 395 Sep 21 02:56 /htdata
```

and `ls -l index.html` should show:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 395 Sep 21 02:56 index.html
```

You can fix your permissions using this command:

```
chmod -R g+w /htdata
```

which means give group write permission (`g+w`) to directory `/htdata` and all content under that directory recursively (`-R`).